# using variable in for loop to specify index of an array in verilog

Tags: arrays, variables, verilog

I am a newbie in verilog. As  variables can not be assigned to index of an array, how I can code this one in verilog, so no compilation error will occur?

```
module strMatch();

reg [15:0]str;
integer i;

reg [10*8-1:0]searchBuffer;

initial
begin
str = "ab";
searchBuffer = "qwertabjkl";

for (i=10;i>=2;i++)
    begin
   if(searchBuffer[(8*i-1:8*(i-2)]==str[15:0])
       begin
           $display("i");
       end
    end // end of for
end // end of initial

endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you have an extra bracket in your if statement which is causing a syntax error.  However even after fixing that your code is still incorrect since you're using `i` on both sides of your bit selection.

If you're taking a slice, *one* of the indices has to be constant.  Verilog has a special notation for taking a constant range:

```
if (searchBuffer[8*i+:16]==str[15:0])
```

This will use `8*i` as the base and take a slice of `16` bits. Working example on [EDA Playground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/3SN).

Note there is also a `-` bit select:

```
  reg [15:0] big_vect; 
  reg [0:15] little_vect; 

  big_vect[lsb_base_expr    +: width_expr] 
  little_vect[msb_base_expr +: width_expr] 

  big_vect[msb_base_expr    -: width_expr] 
  little_vect[lsb_base_expr -: width_expr]
```